# Is there any way for me to disable my activity from appearing on the new right column on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy

In the most recent Facebook change, they introduced a side bar on the right of the screen with every action my contacts make. From commenting on other statuses (even in statuses belonging to their contacts which are not my contacts).

Is there any way to disable my activity from appearing there in my contacts' Facebook home page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Just like wall posts, photos and other stuffs on Facebook, people can view only those items for which they have permission to. So, if your friend has set his wall permission to 'public' or 'friend of friends', all your friends would get your activity on his wall in their ticker.

Comment: What about developing a programmatic tool to automatically make every element in activity log invisible?

Answer (score 0):

well if you confine your status bar to a certain friend list it will only show to certain friends, if that helps...
however what i have found is that if one of those friends has their own status bar set on public it will be seen by others.

i dont think you can get rid of it all together - although ive two other accounts i did one time as a mess for my cats...they funnily do not have as many friends as i and i notice those new settings are not on their pages.  I think i read somewhere too...that if you have less than a certain amount of friends you wont have the new settings...not sure about it though.